# pgrouting query

Tags: pgrouting

I saw on the pgrouting workshop the following way to calculate a route:
http://workshop.pgrouting.org/chapters/advanced.html

```
SELECT seq, id1 AS node, id2 AS edge, cost FROM pgr_dijkstra('
                SELECT gid AS id,
                         source::integer,
                         target::integer,
                         length * c.cost AS cost
                        FROM ways, classes c
                        WHERE class_id = c.id',
                30, 60, false, false);
```

In the part :

> length * c.cost AS cost

Is it possible to multiply the length with any value that I want to? (e.g **length * otherTable.columnValue** )

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: Top :) I will donate to those guys , they deserve it !!